# PhantomJS is taking more time to a load page than cURL

Tags: javascript, curl, phantomjs

Why does PhantomJS require so much time to load pages than other modules like cURL and `file_get_contents`?

I've tried loading google with PhantomJS as well as cURL. cURL took only 20-50ms to load, but PhantomJS took 730ms, even with `load-images` option set to `false`.
What may be the reason for slowness of PhantomJS?

I've tested the time difference inside page load's callback function, immediately.

Here is my code:

```
var page = require("webpage").create();
 page.viewportSize = { width: 1024, height: 768 };

page.open('$url', function(status) {
    console.log('PhantomJS load time:', Date.now() - start);
    page.render('screenshot.png');
    phantom.exit();
 });
```

What methods I can use to improve the page load speed to maximum possible extent, in general or for PhantomJS?

Comment: You could abort loading of some assets but then your screenshots would look messed up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PhantomJS is a full browser (headless, but still a browser). A full browser with an empty cache needs to do many requests to get all page resources and wait until the page is rendered. You can use the `--disk-cache=true` option to let PhantomJS cache some data for subsequent requests, but it will still be much much slower than cURL.

cURL makes only one request without rendering anything. Of course it's much faster, because it's not a browser.

Comment: Thanks for that tip about disk cache. I understand it takes time to load all resources. But is that possible to run the callback immediately after source code is downloaded and DOM is constructed?

Comment: The PhantomJS documentation doesn't make it clear when the `page.open()` callback is called, but in my experience it is as soon as all non-async resources are loaded and the DOM is built. If you want to do something useful with the page then you should wait for the full page load. If you can live with a partial DOM, you can try to use [`waitFor()`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js) to wait for a specific element outside of the `page.open()` callback.